# Fat-Free-Framework / F3 access a hive variable in a mapper callback

Tags: fat-free-framework

I'm using the Fat Free Framework ORM Mapper functionality to insert a set of records passed from the client in an array. The Mapper function has callbacks to for aftersave which pass an array of keys and the mapper object.

I want to be able to loop through the records and use the mapper to insert the records one by one, storing the inserted record's id in an array ('resultsArray') which is set in the F3 hive in the parent function:

```
function myFunction (\Base $f3, $params) {

    // array of records to insert
    $mappedArray = json_decode( $f3->get('BODY'), true );

    $f3->set('mapper', new mapper($db,'mytable'));
    $mapper = $f3->get('mapper');

    // create an array in the hive to store the results of the inserts
    $f3->set('resultsArray', array()); 

    // set mapper callbacks
    $mapper->aftersave(function($self,$pkeys){
        // update the resultsArray in the hive?
    });

    $recordsInArray = count($mappedArray);

    // loop through the array of objects
    for ($loop = 0; $loop<$recordsInArray; $loop++){

        $newRecord = $mappedArray[$loop];            

       try{
            // clear the mapper down
            $mapper->reset();
            // set the array in the hive
            $f3->set('data', $newRecord );
            $mapper->copyFrom('data');    
            $mapper->save();

        } catch(\PDOException $e) {
            // do something
            exit;
        }
    }        

    echo "done";
}
```

Is there a way to access the resultsArray variable I set in the hive in the aftersave callback?

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you need to do all these things to achieve what you want?
To be able to store the IDs of inserted records and put it in the F3's hive, I would do the following:

```php
<?php
function myFunction (\Base $f3, $params) {
    // array of records to insert
    $mappedArray = json_decode( $f3->get('BODY'), true );
    //mapper (no need to put it into hive):
    $mapper = new mapper($db,'mytable');
    // array with IDs:
    $resultsArray = [];
    // loop through the array of objects
    for ($loop = 0; $loop<count($mappedArray); $loop++){

       try{
            // clear the mapper down
            $mapper->reset();
            // map the content (no need to put it in the hive):
            $mapper->copyFrom($mappedArray[$loop]);
            // insert new record:
            $mapper->save();
            // get the ID of the inserted record and put it in the array:
            $resultsArray[] = $mapper->_id;
        } catch(\PDOException $e) {
            // do something
            exit;
        }
    }
    // put the array of IDs in the hive:
    $f3->set("newIDs", $resultsArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the hive within the aftersave handler with the php `use` feature:

```
function myFunction (\Base $f3, $params) {
    // ...
    $mapper->aftersave(function($self,$pkeys) use($f3) {
        $f3->get('resultsArray');
    });
}
```